# Как сделать на Qt окно выполнения процесса с логгирование всех ошибок и просто хода выполнения

Tags: qt, exec, qdialog

Главное, чтобы процесс отражался в реальном времени. То есть нужна периодическая отрисовка с дополнением новой информации, там например в качестве накопления лога QLabel используется (но не в этом суть).

Не хотелось бы использовать два потока для этого.

То есть понятно, что нужно QDialog с exec запускать (это у нас в главном потоке), чтобы он мог отрисовывать себя. Но как перед этим запустить команду на выполнение самого процесса (там с оборудованием общение происходит) пока не пойму.

То есть либо я в запуская команду и приходится ждать окончания ее выполнения, либо я запуская exec и пока не завершу exec команду запустить не могу.

Получается замкнутый круг.

Comment: Чтобы не получался замкнутый круг, надо использовать поток-воркер, который крутит задачу, в то время как основной поток рисует гуй с прогрессом

Comment: Я встречал случай в очень энтерпрайзном софте, когда тяжелая задача крутилась в основном потоке, а для обновления прогресса использовался отдельный процесс, который рисовал окошко и, в который каким-то IPC передавалась информация о прогрессе (и кажется даже была кнопка Cancel, которая кажется даже работала). Но это скорее анекдот, я искренне не рекомендую так делать

Comment: Два потока это нормальный рабочий вариант, но не хочется создавать второй поток, следить там за ним, закрывать корректно.  У нас приложение десктопное простое, стандартно один поток.

Comment: Я не могу оценить до деталей, что Вам нужно, но вроде бы можно `QEventLoop` использовать.

Comment: QEvenrLoop реализован в exec у QDialog и используется у нас в окне индикации процесса. Тут все логично QEventLoop нужен.

Comment: Похоже я понял как разорвать замкнутый круг - надо запускать команду **отложенно по таймеру**, кстати как сами Троли и практиковали отрисовку, ресайзинг и т.д.
Потом по коду идёт **exec** окна индикации, а потом срабатывает таймер и начинает выполняться команда, которая через сигналы наполняет окно индикации контентом.
И получается у нас всё-таки один поток, а не два.

Comment: P.Dorofeev Я имею в виду [вот эту технику](https://pavelk.ru/qeventloop-and-connectdisconnect-lambda-function/)
Указывайте никнейм в сообщение, если желаете, чтобы ответили оперативнее.